# Insecure world writable dir /mnt/c in PATH, mode 040777 in vagrant

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, vagrant

I am trying to issue vagrant up on windows linux subsystem and this error is appearing.

```
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/vagrant-2.2.7/lib/vagrant/util/which.rb:37: warning: Insecure world writable dir /mnt/c in PATH, mode 040777
Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:

Vagrant is unable to use the VirtualBox provider from the Windows Subsystem for
Linux without access to the Windows environment. Enabling this access must be
done with caution and an understanding of the implications. For more information
on enabling Windows access and using VirtualBox from the Windows Subsystem for
Linux, please refer to the Vagrant documentation:

  https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/other/wsl.html
```

I already tried to remove and re-install vagrant and thats not the issue.
I was doing

```
chmod go-w /mnt/c
```

for every insecure world writable but for /mnt/c this command doesnt work.
Can someone help me?

Also I already tried doing

```
[automount]
options="metadata,umask=0033"
```

in etc/wsl.conf a file which I created and it didnt work.
I cant even issue vagrant ssh.

Comment: The warning is not the cause of your problem.  Have you read the documentation at the URL?